# How to combine ILogger and Application Insights

Tags: c#, .net, logging, azure-application-insights

I am used to Azure Application Insights and I am writing a new service in which I would like to use the `ILogger` interface, coming from the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` library.

However, in order to fully utilize Application Insights capabilities, I need to have some sort of **activity id** per each trace, that allows me to group together related traces.

How could I integrate those together without losing the above functionality?

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Logging

If the above does not help, then post back.